# Tkinter : Can't get register function to work

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

after a lot of research, I come to you for help.
On the Entry Wdiget from tkinter, there is a validatecommand option you can pass. The documentation seem to say that the function you pass as argument first needs to be registered via the `.register()` function so it can become a callback function.

Here's what I found : [Tkinter 8.5 reference](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry-validation.html)

So it should be something like this :

```
class Window(tk.Tk):                      

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.entry = EntryBoxFormated()
        self.entry.pack()

class EntryBoxFormated (tk.Entry):

    def __init__ (self, min=None, max=None, precision=None, type=None):   

        if (min == None):
            self.min = 0
        if (max == None):
            self.max = 10
        if (precision == None):
            self.precision = 4
        if (type == None or type != 'string'):
            self.type = "float"

        self.entryTkValue = self.initEntryValue()

        cmd = self.register(self.entryFloatValidation)
        super().__init__(textvariable = self.entryTkValue, text = self.entryTkValue, validate=tk.ALL, validatecommand = cmd)

    def initEntryValue(self):
        initVal = "0"
        if (self.precision > 0):
            initVal += "."
            for i in range(0,self.precision):
                initVal += "0"
        return tk.StringVar(value=initVal)

    def entryFloatValidation(self):

        tempString = self.entryTkValue.get()
        n = len(tempString)
        nbPoints = 0
        res = True
        i=0

        while (i<n):
            if (tempString[i] < '0' or tempString[i] > '9'):
                if (tempString[i] == ',' or tempString[i] == ';'):
                    tempString[i] == '.'

                if (tempString[i] == '.'):
                    nbPoints += 1
                    if (nbPoints > 1):
                        res = False
                else:
                    res = False

        if (res):
            if (float(tempString) < self.min or float(tempString) > self.max):
                res = False
            else:
                self.delete(0,tk.END)
                self.insert(0,tempString)

        return res


if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    window = Window()    
    window.mainloop()
    window.quit()
```

But with this, I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/home/aubin/PyzoWorkspace/Interface/TESTS/topic.py", line 75, in
<module>
    window = Window()   File "/home/aubin/PyzoWorkspace/Interface/TESTS/topic.py", line 9, in
__init__
    self.entry = EntryBoxFormated()   File "/home/aubin/PyzoWorkspace/Interface/TESTS/topic.py", line 28, in
__init__
    cmd = self.register(self.entryFloatValidation)   File "/home/aubin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1366,
in _register
    self.tk.createcommand(name, f) AttributeError: 'EntryBoxFormated' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

If I skip the call to register in the init() of the class EntryBoxFormated, I don't get any erro but the window doesn't show.

Am I forgeting anything ?

Thanks in advance.

Edit :
Is there a way to pass around that ? I thought the following lines but it doesn't (no error but the window doesn't appear)

```
super().__init__(textvariable = self.entryTkValue, text = self.entryTkValue, validate=tk.ALL)
cmd = self.register(self.entryFloatValidation)
self.configure(validatecommand=cmd)
```

Comment: You didn't call `super().__init__()` in your `EntryBoxFormated` constructor.

Comment: Actually, i do, this is the last line of the constructor

Comment: Ok, but you have to do it _before_ calling `self.register`.

Comment: I can't reproduce that "window doesn't appear" thing. That code works just fine.

Comment: Ok well, might be a distibution problem, it's weird. Thanks anyway. What editor are you using ?

Comment: I don't see what difference the _editor_ could make, but I'm using CPython 3.6.5 on linux.

Comment: Yeah I don't either, that's pretty weird, i'm using the same version with anaconda. I'll try another editor and computer. You can close the topic. Thanks again.